# Why does Mathematica give 1, 1/2, -1/8 and not 1, -1/2, 3/8 for ${1/2 \choose 0}, {1/2 \choose 1}, {1/2 \choose 2}$

Tags: computational-mathematics

$\binom{-1/2}{n}=\left (\frac{1}{n!}\right )\left (\frac{-1}{2}\right )\left (\frac{-3}{2}\right )\dots\frac{-(2n-1)}{2}=(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2n!!}$

The first three values are 1, -1/2, 3/8.

```
binom[n_] := Binomial[1/2, n]
Table[binom[i], {i, 0, 2}]

{1, 1/2, -(1/8)}
```

According to the documentation:

> In general, (n m) is defined by 
>   $\Gamma$(n+1)/($\Gamma$(m+1)$\Gamma$(n-m+1)) or suitable limits
>   of this.

However ${-1/2 \choose 1}$= `Gamma[1/2]/(Gamma[2] Gamma[-1/2])` gives the correct value: `-(1/2)`
Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you asking about $\binom{-1/2}{1}$ or $\binom{1/2}{1}$?

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$
\binom{1/2}{0}=1
\qquad
\binom{1/2}{1}=\frac{1/2}{1}=\frac{1}{2}
\qquad
\binom{1/2}{2}=\frac{(1/2)\cdot(1/2-1)}{2!}=-\frac{1}{8}
$$
whereas
$$
\binom{-1/2}{0}=1
\qquad
\binom{-1/2}{1}=\frac{-1/2}{1}=-\frac{1}{2}
\qquad
\binom{-1/2}{2}=\frac{(-1/2)\cdot(-1/2-1)}{2!}=\frac{3}{8}
$$